# Javascript regex to match 'int'

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regex to match *INT* or *INT,* or *INT ,* to split  a String, the String could also contain similar words like INTEGER, INT444, INTEGER2, etc. but they should be ignored.

```
var str = 'INTEGER INT, INTEGER2 INT , TEST INT';
str = str.split(/INT[\,\)\s]*[^A-Za-z0-0]/gi);
```

The regex only matches *INT,* (INT + comma) and *INT ,* (INT + space + comma) but not *INT* (only the word INT).
Any help?

Answer (score 1):

You mean this?

```
var str = 'INTEGER INT, INTEGER2 INT , TEST INT';
str = str.split(/INT(?=(?: ?,|$))/gi); // ["INTEGER ", ", INTEGER2 ", " , TEST ", ""]
```

That's called forward lookahead, more about it here: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/redev2.shtml

Comment: the last element must be `' TEST '`

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are looking for word boundaries `\b`

```
\bINT\b
```

`\b` will match the boundary between a character included in `\w` and other characters.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your question, but I think this is what you were asking for.

```
INT,|INT |INT(?![A-Za-z0-9])
```

Answer (score 0):

How about :

```
/INT\b\s*,?/
```

on your example, it gives :

```
["INTEGER ", " INTEGER2 ", " TEST "]
```